# Showing nested form text_field as text in index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, fields-for

I'm totally new to Rails, so I'm sorry for the stupid question:

This is the code to generate my form and its nested form:

```
<%= form_for @job do |form| %>          
    <div><%= form.label :department %><%= form.text_field :department %></div>
    <div><%= form.label :enabled %><%= form.check_box :enabled %></div>

    <!-- job description form -->
    <%= form.fields_for :job_descriptions do |subform| %>
        <div><%= subform.hidden_field :language %></div>
        <div><%= subform.object.language %></div>
        <div><%= subform.label "Job Name" %><%= subform.text_field :title %></div>
        <div><%= subform.label "Header" %><%= subform.text_field :short_text %></div>
        <div><%= subform.label "Content" %><%= subform.text_area :text %></div>
    <% end %>
    <!-- end of job description form -->
    <div><%= form.submit %></div>
<% end %>
```

While this is part of the **index.html.erb** where I want to display **text_fields** from my **subform** such as **:title**, **:short_text** and **:text** as static text (I'm trying with **:title** in this particular case):

```
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
    <li>
        <%= job.title %>
        <%= job.department %>
        <%= job.enabled %>
        <%= link_to 'Show', job_path(job) %>
        <%= link_to 'Delete', job_path(job), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
    </li>
<% end %>
```

The error I get is:

```
undefined method `title' for #<Job:0x007fcdde2001a8>
```

My **job.rb** file looks like this:

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :job_descriptions, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :job_descriptions

    def self.languages
        [:de, :en]
    end
end
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: You don't have #title as an attribute on your Job objects, only a JobDescription has a #title. I guess you want a separate JobDescription for each language, is that it? Do you want to show every JobDescription on the jobs index page, or the JobDescription for one language, or what?

Comment: I want to show every title of every JobDescription in the jobs index page, I solved adding JobDescription in the JobsController, it was missing. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= form_for @job do |form| %>
  ...
  <%= form.fields_for :job_descriptions do |subform| %>
    <% if subform.object.active? %>
      <%= subform.text_field :title %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  ...
<% end %>
```